# WebRTC Safari in iOS (12.1). The first live broadcast pauses when a second remote stream is connected

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mobile-safari

A local user has given access to the camera and microphone. It is seen and heard by other participants. But the local user sees and hears only one remote participant. Because video streams from other participants are paused. How to make video automatically plays with all participants in a video conference?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by updating iOS to version 13